# Surprisingly Slow Standard Deviation in R

Tags: r

I am calculating standard deviations on an expanding window where at each point I recalculate the standard deviation.  This seems like a fairly straightforward thing to do that should be relatively fast.  However, it takes a lot longer than you might think (~45 seconds).  Am I missing something here?  In Matlab this is quite fast.

```
t0 <- proc.time()[[3]]
z <- rep(0, 7000)
x <- rnorm(8000)
for(i in 1000:8000){
##    print(i)
    z[i] <- sd(x[1:i])
}
print(proc.time()[[3]]- t0)
```

Comment: It's probably the for loop with memory slicing that's killing you. The call to sd will not be the bottleneck.

Comment: Also you're having to grow `z` because you start it with only 7000 but then put something in spots 7001:8000.

Comment: And your loop contains 7001 iterations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might also try an algorithm that updates the standard deviation (well, actually, the sum of squares of differences from the mean) as you go.  On my system this reduces the time from ~0.8 seconds to ~0.002 seconds.

```
n <- length(x)
m <- cumsum(x)/(1:n)
m1 <- c(NA,m[1:(n-1)])
ssd <- (x-m)*(x-m1)
v <- c(0,cumsum(ssd[-1])/(1:(n-1)))
z <- sqrt(v)
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance for details.

Also see the answers to this question: [Efficient calculation of matrix cumulative standard deviation in r](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765374/210673)

Comment: Yep: always better to vectorize than to use *apply, and always better to use *apply than for/while .

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: "Yes" to your first assertion, "no" to your second. `apply` is just a wrapper using a for-loop. Look at the code.

Comment: And even better to use a more appropriate algorithm.

Comment: @Dwin - `apply` might simply use a scripted for-loop but `lapply` and `vapply` certainly do not... And R core can improve `apply` in future releases...

Comment: @Tommy: Got any great examples? Prof Ripley is not as much of an enthusiast about the performance gains as you are: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02/archive/102284.html

Comment: @DWin - The compiler in R 2.14 can probably help, but currently the function lookup within a for-loop is not as efficient as the one in `lappy`/`vapply`. So calling a function that does some simple thing is much faster with `lapply`/`vapply`. I have a sample that doesn't fit here that is 4x faster with `vapply`...

Comment: (karma whining...)So a comment partially incorrectly correcting my comment gets more votes than the original.  Life is so cruel :-)

Answer (score 4):

*Edited to fix some typos, sorry.*

This takes ~1.3 seconds on my machine:

```
t0 <- proc.time()[[3]]
x <- rnorm(8000)
z <- sapply(1000:8000,function(y){sd(x[seq_len(y)])})
print(proc.time()[[3]]- t0)
```

and I'd be willing to bet there are even faster ways of doing this. Avoid explicit `for` loops!

Comment: Take the `rnorm()` call out of the timing on both approaches as it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely better ways of doing this, this is more a thought experiment.  However, another interesting conclusion is that when I run this on my windows version of R it is much faster (~.8 seconds).  I am currently using a shared UNIX server with (with solaris operating system) which is probably contributing to the slowness.

Answer (score 0):

When a somewhat similar question about a cumulative variance and a cumularive kurtosis operation came up in rhelp a few days ago, here is what I offered :

```
daily <- rnorm(1000000)
mbar <- mean(daily)
cumvar <-  cumsum( (daily-cumsum(daily)/1:length(daily) )^2)
cumskew <- cumsum( (daily-cumsum(daily)/1:length(daily))^3)/cumvar^(3/2)
```

It's certainly faster than the sapply method but may be comparable to Aaron's.

```
 system.time( cumvar <-  cumsum( (daily-cumsum(daily)/1:length(daily) )^2) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.037   0.026   0.061 
 system.time(cumsd <- sqrt(cumvar) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.009   0.005   0.013
```

Comment: Are you sure this is giving the right answer?  I think the cumulative means aren't being used properly.  Compare `cumvar[5]` with `var(daily[1:5])`.

Comment: My cumvar()iances are (supposed to be) the sums of variances to an index. Perhaps not the same as was requested. May need to take out one of the cumsums and get the denominator fixed before there is agreement.

Comment: No, not quite the same as here.