# For-loop error and min 2.5% and max 97.5% percentile in R

Tags: r, for-loop, percentile

I have a data set with 41 rows and 21 columns. In DF, each row represents energy data in 15 minute interval of the day (from 10am-8pm). each column represents selected days within a month month.

I need to figure out load variability (standard deviation/ mean) b/w two lines in each column using the following equation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/inOKV.jpg]

I.e, between the 1st and 2nd; 1st, 2nd and 3rd; 1st-4th; 1st-5th; etc. element of each column.

I keep getting NA values in "lv" and wonder why. The end result, lv should have a dataframe of 41x21, same as df but with load variability.

Also, how do I also get 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles within the loop other than load variability?

```
x <- df[1:41,1:21]

#calculate load variability 
count = 0
i=1{
for (i in 1:41){
     count = count+1  
     mean = sum (x[1:l,])/count
     diff = ((x-mean)^2)
     lv= sqrt((diff/(count+1)-1)/mean)
         i = i+1
  }
}
lv
```

lv ends up with null values (NA).

Comment: For a start, inside you are reassigning `x` which means, inside the scope of your loop, you will lose your orignal data.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate sd/mean for each row, or are you really trying to calculate it across all the data for the first `i` rows in your loop?

Comment: I am trying to sd/mean for each row.

Comment: First:  what is `df` ?  Next: you reduced x from a 41 x 63 array to a 1 x 63 array, so the next time thru the loop,  you  exceed the current dimensions of x.  You neglected to post that you got an error message.

Comment: The question still is not clear, even after the editing. You ref to the load variability *betweeen* columns. However, your formula, which is just sd/mean is a measure for a single set of data. You also say you want the result to have the same dimensions as the original data. So, what do you want the first entry in the first row to be? The sd/mean of a single data point, i.e. 0?

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best explaining complicated tasks that I have been working here, but I guess I was not successful at it. I resolved this issue now with some help. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate sd/mean for each row, try:

```
apply(x, 1, sd)/rowMeans(x)
```

If you want the 2.5% and 97.5% confidence level for each row try:

```
apply(x, 1, quantile, c(.025, 0.975))
```

Comment: ninja'd!   But quick nit:  flip it so it's  sd/mean :-)

Comment: too quick on the cut & paste!

Comment: Thanks, but how do you calculate that in a for-loop?

Comment: The whole point is to use `apply` to avoid using a loop. But if you must :-),  just mod your code: delete `x<-x[1:i....` line and replace the calculation with `mean = sum(x[i,])/count`  .  Note also that using "mean" and "diff" for variables is not recommended since those are functions in the base R packages.

Comment: As Carl points out, the apply avoids the need for a loop: it just gives the results for every row. Think vectorised!

Comment: I guess I was not clear in my question. I would need sd/mean b/w rows for each column. So, I would have 41x21 matrix of lv even for the end result.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for each column: get loading for element 1 and 2, then 1, 2 and 3, then 1-4, 1-5, etc.? The result of which will have 1 fewer row than the original data?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after several tries (and some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765374/efficient-calculation-of-matrix-cumulative-standard-deviation-in-r)), I finally have:

```
cumul_loading <- function(x, leave.nan=FALSE){
  ind_na <- !is.na(x)
  nn <- cumsum(ind_na)
  x[!ind_na] <- 0

  cumul_mean <- cumsum(x) / nn
  cumul_sd <- sqrt(cumsum(x^2) / (nn-1) - (cumsum(x))^2/(nn-1)/nn)

  if(leave.nan) return(cumul_sd / cumul_mean) else 
    return((cumul_sd / cumul_mean)[-1])
}
```

It should have a few bugs (such as what to do with NAs), but it should now work with an `apply` function. The `leave.nan` argument optionally leaves the NaN produced when `n_len - 1 = 0`

```
apply(x, 2, cumul_loading)
```