# Calculating standard deviation on large table

Tags: r

I have a large table of market data to work with, and it looks like this:

```
stock    date          return
1        "2000-01-01"  0.01
1        "2000-01-02"  0.02
1        "2000-01-03"  0.03
...
2        "2000-01-01"  0.04
2        "2000-01-02"  0.05
...
```

I'm trying to add a column that is standard deviation of the returns from that day and prior.  So for each stock, the first date won't have a SD value, and it would just be "NA".  But then the next dates would filter the data frame for all the rows that have the same stock number and have dates less than that row's date, then take the standard deviation of all of the returns.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Or does there exist a library that would provide a workaround?

Currently, I'm using a for loop that goes through every row.  However, my data frame is very large (15 million rows), so the filtering takes very long if I have to do it for every row.  I've tried to optimize it a little bit by filtering first for the stock number (then by the date later), and that way I only have to do that step if the stock number changes from row to row.  It's a little faster, but still not great.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the SD of each day with the prior day?  It is better to show a small example with the expected output

Comment: I guess this may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765374/1191259