# Improve efficiency of loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, coding-efficiency

I've been working on a code in R that calculates standard deviation (SD) across my data. I've done it as a loop where it looks at the 1st and 2nd row, calculates the SD for each column in that row and then totals the SD. It then repeats next looking at rows 1, 2 and 3 then rows 1 to 4 etc.

It works completely fine on my test dataset which contains 19 rows and 128 columns however my actual dataset has around 340,000 rows and 128 columns. When I run this code it fails to reach the end slowing down at around the 100,000 mark I think from when I added a printing function to show me which loop its on.

Here is the code:

```
site <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)

SDCalculate <- function(data){
  
  sd_totals <- data.frame(SD=0)
  
  for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
    
    sd_values <- data.frame()
    
    cat(i,"\n")
    
    for (j in 4:ncol(data)){
      
      list <- c(data[1:i,j])
      
      sd_values <- rbind(sd_values, sd(list))
      
    }
    
    sd_totals <-rbind(sd_totals, sum(sd_values))
    
  }
  
  data <- sd_totals
}


results<- SDCalculate(site)
```

I was wondering if there's any way I can improve the efficiency of my code so that it works? Or would it be worth running it in Python instead? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't grow vectors. Pre-allocate them and then fill them in. I.e, `sd_totals <-rbind(sd_totals, sum(sd_values))` is bad. Outside of the loop, do `sd_totals <- numeric(sizeOfFinalResults)` and then `sd_totals[currentIteration] <- sum(sd_values)`. Also with your other vector. When you grow vectors with `rbind` and similar, you are making copies of these vectors in each pass of the loop. This gets expensive as your vector size grows.

Comment: If the printing of `i` slows you down, maybe just print every 1000th `i` or so. For parallelisation, you could have a look at the `foreach` package which supports `for` loop like parallelisation.

Comment: You might want to look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765374/efficient-calculation-of-matrix-cumulative-standard-deviation-in-r Basically your calculating the cumulative standard deviation but have a very memory inefficient approach. You can use the function in link and then send ```as.matrix(data[, 4:length(data)])``` to get your result quicker.

Comment: @Cole Thank you so much that linked question was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As written, SDCalculate does not return any result, last line should be `data` or `sd_totals`. If you have 340000 rows and 128 columns the inner loop will be executed more than 43 millons times. The first loop selects a data matrix adding the next row, then for the new matrix you calculate `sd` by column and then biuld a one column matrix using rbind, but then you get the sum of sd. So why don't just sum the sd within the loop.

```
SDCalculate2 <- function(data){
  
  SD <- 0 # do not need data.frame(SD=0)
  
  for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
  
    sd_sum <- 0 # do not need a data frame sd_values

    for (j in 4:ncol(data)){
      sd_sum <- sd_sum + sd(data[1:i,j])
    }
    # do not need rbind
    SD[i] <- sd_sum
  }

  # output 
  as.data.frame(SD)
}
```

Another option, I didn't try performance, without inner loop for

```
SDCalculate3 <- function(data){
  SD <- 0
  for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
    SD[i] <- sum(apply(data[1:i,4:ncol(data)],2,sd))
  }
  data.frame(SD)
}
```